# Laravel relationships and pivot tables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I'm working on my first ever laravel app, now I'm at the stage of creating some relationships for my content types.

In the app I can create an appointment which in the process of doing so also saves the details and creates a new client. However I want my user to be able to see the their clients "history" and see all appointments they've booked.

So far I've added hasMany relationship to my client model and the inverse hasOne in the appointment model. Therefore my thinking so far is that a client can have many appointments but an appointment can have only one client.

However...

I'm really struggling with connecting both together as ideally I need to do something like this:-

For X client id get all appointments that match client id

In this context is this where would you use a pivot table to manage this? If so where do you place the logic to handle the attaching/deattaching of IDs in the model(s)?

Or is there something I'm missing from my call as my appointment function in my client model only has the following: -

```
       return $this->hasMany('App\Appointment');
```

Do I need to pass anything else?

I've read the docs and I'm utterly clueless and coming from a WP background so any help at all would be fantastic!

Comment: What do you mean by "For X client id get all appointments that match client id"

Comment: It's basically sudo code for $client_appointments = Appointment::find()

If that makes sense.

Comment: So is this a question about database design? The way you describe it you'll have an `attachments` table with a `client_id` column, thus having a one-to-many relation from clients to attachments. Then you can assign that relation using `hasMany` like you did. There are optional parameters after the one you defined, for instance laravel assumes the column name is `client_id` if your class is named `class Client {}`. See https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many . Then finally, in your code you can call `Client::with(['appointments'])->find(1)`.

Comment: Yeah this is more a db design question, ah ok so if I do everything correctly, I wouldn't have to use attach() or anything like that?

Comment: You don't need to implement a pivot table concept here. As you just need one to many relationships which can be easily handled by defining the functions in both models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're talking about [a one-to-many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) you don't need a pivot table. Instead your `appointments` table should have a `client_id` column that links to the client.

To get all appointments for a client you just need to get the `appointments` property (assuming your relationship method is also called `appointments()`:

```
$appointments = $client->appointments;

// OR

$appointments = \App\Client::find($client_id)->appointments;
```

Since that property doesn't exist on the class, Laravel will look for a relationship method with the same name. Once it found it Laravel will query the appointments table for entries with that client's ID and return them [in a Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-collections).

The relationship method also helps when storing a new appointment:

```
$client->appointments()->create(['date' => request('date'), ...]);
```

Here you don't need to manually add the `client_id` to the appointment since Laravel knows about the relationship.

You have some flexibility in naming of your methods/table columns etc. but I usually find it best just to stick with [the Laravel conventions](https://webdevetc.com/blog/laravel-naming-conventions).

Comment: I had to tweak some of your code however this worked for me thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the One-to-many relationship here for your current context.

```
<?php
// Appointment model
class Appointment extends Model
{
    ...
    /**
     * Get the client associated with the Appointment.
     */
    public function client()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Client', 'client_id');
    }
    ...
}

// client model
class Client extends Model
{
    ...
    /**
     * Get the Appointments associated with the client.
     */
    public function appointments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Appointment');
    }
    ...
}

// query to fetch client's appointments
Client::find(1)->with(['appointments']);
```

Comment: `With` and `find` calls should be reversed to eager load the data

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach

```
//In your Appointment Model
class Appointment extends Model
{
    public function client()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Client'); 
    }
}

//In your Client Model
class Client extends Model
{
    public function appointments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Appointment'); //if the foreign column in your appointments table is named different the client_id, the specify that column ('App\Appointment', 'id_of_client)
    }
    ...
}

// query to fetch client's appointments
$client = Client::findOrFail(1)->with(['appointments']);
```